# Advice on direction for an Android App to receive data from other devices

Tags: android

For this question, I am not looking for specific answers, or code or anything, but moreso suggestions on what techniques to employ to accomplish my goal.

I am very new to Android development. I have a bit of a background in Java.

The App I'm looking to build would have two types of users. The Narrator and the Participant.

The Participants would fill out a few fields, and click a button. This data would be integer and string values. Nothing terribly complex. The participants don't really need any sort of feedback beyond success or failure.

The Narrator's app would receive this information, and build a list displaying the information the Participants sent. Possibly the Narrator is able to send a message to the Participant devices prompting them to fill out and send their inputs, but not necessary.

What I am looking for is direction on which sorts of methods or techniques to accomplish this. It could be accomplished over Bluetooth, but even accomplishing it over the internet is arguably better.

It would need to be able to generate a unique session that users can locate and "connect to", as well.

If there are other questions that have info that would help me, feel free to link them. I assume there are. The rub is that I wasn't exactly sure how to ask this question with enough brevity to yield useful search results.

Thanks very much.

Comment: *For this question, I am not looking for specific answers, or code or anything, but moreso **suggestions on what techniques to employ to accomplish my goal.*** sorry, but that is exactly what SO is not for

Comment: I didn't mean that I wanted people to NOT share code, so much as I was not trying to get someone to write my app for me. If people want to provide concrete, specific answers, that's even more helpful. Clearly I phrased it poorly, as I was merely trying to qualify what my expectations were. Actual code would obviously be even more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Look at realtime cloud db solutions to create the realtime, connect to session that you want to create.

In your app create a registration activity where the user can register as a participant or narrator. Store the user details on the cloud once register with a usertype key under your user model/map.

For example to define a value to usertype use like this.
usertype = 0 for participant
usertype = 1 for narrator

For your main activity you can create 2 layouts:

Layout1 (participant)
Layout2(narrator)

When user login you read the usertype value and assign layout in the oncreate method.

Example

if(usertype==0){
setContentView(Layout1)}

Within the layouts you will add your edittexts, views and buttons as per required for narrators and participants.

You will also write your functions for narrator in its own class/void and the same for participant.

Then use the usertype value to access the defined classes/voids.

You can have a look at firebase as a realtime database or there are plenty other options.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

So according to your explanation, participants will send something to other users which are Narrator. So something like chat system. In that case, you can use Firebase Realtime database. First, see how Firebase real-time database works. You can check [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-an-android-chat-app-using-firebase--cms-27397) to get an idea.

So when participants fill up something it must receive by the narrator. When participants submit something you just need to send a push notification to all participants. So when participants click on the notifications you will redirect him to a specific activity and can load the participant's submitted form in that.